# Widget App is not working on Rooted phones, why?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, rooted-device

I created an App / Widget for Android and published it in the marked. The Market tell me that the App is working on any Device because it really needs nothing. 
This is not advertising, I only want to know, why some devices (rooted and/or with a different ROM) cannot download / install the app?
https://market.android.com/details?id=de.mirsoft.clock

I know one guy with a new Galaxy Nexus phone (rooted), he can install the App but he cannot find the Widget in the Widget-Tab on his Phone. 
I also have an Galaxy Nexus and it works great.
Galaxy S2 (rooted, MIUI ROM) also, cannot download it.

Only on rooted Phones, my app is not working, but I can't understand why? What's the different?
The App has no permissions, so where is the problem?

Comment: Problems with Galaxy Nexus might be related to [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6ef964dc4395e979/b6afb30cc3341c01?lnk=raot).

Comment: hm... sounds interessting, becouse i also dont use an activity (only as config for the widget).

Answer (score 0):

I added the LAUNCHER action to the Configuration Activity in the Manifest.xml.
Now the user with the rooted Galaxy Nexus can see the widget in the Widget list but i need to test it again on a phone with a differnet ROM like MIUI. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your app on my HTC Desire (rooted MIUI 2.1.20) and it works fine. I don't see why your friend can't add the widget to his desktop. Rooted phones with a custom ROM that supports widgets work basically the same way as the OTA's.